# removing docinfo in docutils output with HTML5 writer

Tags: python, html, restructuredtext, docutils

With the `docutils` python library, when using the `html5` writer, I cannot find a way *not* to have the docinfo (fields at the beginning of the source) included in the output.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import docutils.io, docutils.core

SOURCE = '''\
:key: value

Title
========

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
'''

docutils_params = {
    'input_encoding': 'utf-8',
}

pub = docutils.core.Publisher(
    source_class=docutils.io.StringInput,
    destination_class=docutils.io.StringOutput)
pub.set_components('standalone', 'restructuredtext', 'html5')
pub.process_programmatic_settings(None, docutils_params, None)
pub.set_source(SOURCE)
pub.publish()

# same thing with parts['body']
body = pub.writer.parts['fragment']

print(body)
```

Here are the first lines of the output:

```
<dl class="docinfo simple">
<dt class="key">key</dt>
<dd class="key"><p>value</p>
</dd>
</dl>
<div class="section" id="title">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

What I don't want is the whole `<dl class="docinfo simple">` element.

The use of the HTML5 writer is set in the line `pub.set_components(...`
If instead I use `html` I don't have this problem, but for my use I need the HTML5 writer and not the standard HTML one.

What's weird is that the documentation seems to say that using `pub.writer.parts['fragment']` (or equivalently `pub.writer.parts['body']`) should remove the docinfo from the output:

> `parts['fragment']` contains the document body (not the HTML ). In other words, it contains the entire document, less the document title, subtitle, **docinfo**, header, and footer.
>
> *source: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html*

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the HTML5 writer of `docutils` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docutils developers identified this as a bug and patched it.

See on the `docutils-users` mailing list [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/mailman/docutils-users/thread/CAJKLPhzoDtZZJ-PUx%2Bw0Q9nwFikwRTapcFwyRJqR-EzbA0i1ug%40mail.gmail.com/#msg36326664)
and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/mailman/docutils-users/thread/pf66qj%24ms5%242%40blaine.gmane.org/#msg36335249)

[@andref's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50659194/3025740) is great, though, thanks for pointing to this package.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [rst2html5](https://pypi.org/project/rst2html5/) instead of Docutils:

```
from rst2html5_ import HTML5Writer
from docutils.core import publish_parts

SOURCE = '''\
:key: value

Title
========

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
'''

parts = publish_parts(writer=HTML5Writer(), source=SOURCE)
print(parts['body'])
```

This is the result:

```
<section id="title">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</section>
```